# Trouble calling Dictionary using Variable using Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have only been working with python for a few months, 
so sorry if I am asking a stupid question. I am having 
a problem calling a dictionary name using a variable.

The problem is, if I use a variable to call a dictionary & [] operators, 
python interprets my code trying to return a single character in the string 
instead of anything within the dictionary list.

To illustrate by an example ... let's say I 
have a dictionary list like below.

---

```
USA={'Capital':'Washington',
     'Currency':'USD'}

Japan={'Capital':'Tokyo',
       'Currency':'JPY'}

China={'Capital':'Beijing',
      'Currency':'RMB'}

country=input("Enter USA or JAPAN or China? ")

print(USA["Capital"]+USA["Currency"])  #No problem -> WashingtonUSD
print(Japan["Capital"]+Japan["Currency"])  #No problem -> TokyoJPY
print(China["Capital"]+China["Currency"])  #No problem -> BeijingRMB
print(country["Capital"]+country["Currency"])  #Error -> TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

---

In the example above, I understand the interpreter 
is expecting an integer because it views the value
of "country" as a string instead of dictionary... 
like if I put country[2] using Japan as input (for example), 
it will return the character "p". But clearly that 
is not what my intent is.

Is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 2):

You should put your countries themselves into a dictionary, with the keys being the country names. Then you would be able to do `COUNTRIES[country]["Capital"]`, etc.

Example:

```
COUNTRIES = dict(
    USA={'Capital':'Washington',
         'Currency':'USD'},
    Japan={'Capital':'Tokyo',
           'Currency':'JPY'},
    ...
)
country = input("Enter USA or Japan or China? ")
print(COUNTRIES[country]["Capital"])
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom, this is very helpful!! I don't think I would have ever considered using another dictionary to wrap the initial dictionary without your help. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Any other way of doing it is **definitely** better than the way I'm about to show.  This way will work, but it is *not pythonic*.  I'm offering it for entertainment purposes, and to show that Python is cool.

```
USA={'Capital':'Washington',
     'Currency':'USD'}

Japan={'Capital':'Tokyo',
       'Currency':'JPY'}

China={'Capital':'Beijing',
      'Currency':'RMB'}

country=input("Enter USA or Japan or China? ")

print(USA["Capital"]+USA["Currency"])  #No problem -> WashingtonUSD
print(Japan["Capital"]+Japan["Currency"])  #No problem -> TokyoJPY
print(China["Capital"]+China["Currency"])  #No problem -> BeijingRMB

# This works, but it is probably unwise to use it.
print(vars()[country]["Capital"] + vars()[country]['Currency'])
```

This works because the built-in function `vars`, when given no arguments, returns a dict of variables (and other stuff) in the current namespace.  Each variable name, as a string, becomes a key in the dict.

But @tom's suggestion is actually a much better one.

Comment: Hi Cody, thank you also for providing an example. I've tried your method also and it also did provide the expected results... I didn't realize you can provide a 'hack-like' method using the built-in vars() function. I think such method can be useful in particular occasions if used properly.